# Merge two datasets but one of them is year_month and the other is year_month_week

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, merge, datetime-format

I practice data merging using R nowadays. Here are simple two data `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                year_month=c(202205,202206,202207,202204,202205,202206,202207),
                points=c(65,58,47,21,25,27,43))

df2<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                year_month_week=c(2022052,2022053,2022061,2022043,2022051,2022052),
                temperature=c(36.1,36.3,36.6,34.3,34.9,35.3))
```

For `df1`, `202205` in `year_month` column means May 2022.
For `df2`, `2022052` in `year_month_week` column means 2nd week of May, 2022.
I want to merge `df1` and `df2` with respect to `year_month_week`. So, all the elements of `df2` are left, but some values of `df2` can be copied.
For example, `202205` in `year_month` includes `2022052` and `2022053`. There is no column `points` in `df2`. In this case, `65` is copied. My expected output looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               year_month_week=c(2022052,2022053,2022061,2022043,2022051,2022052),
               temperature=c(36.1,36.3,36.6,34.3,34.9,35.3),
               points=c(65,65,58,21,25,25))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary `year_month` column in `df2` by taking the first six characters of `year_month_week`, then do a left join on `df1` by `year_month` and `id` before removing the temporary column.

Using tidyverse, we could do this as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  mutate(year_month = as.numeric(substr(year_month_week, 1, 6))) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c('year_month', 'id')) %>%
  select(-year_month)
#>   id year_month_week temperature points
#> 1  1         2022052        36.1     65
#> 2  1         2022053        36.3     65
#> 3  1         2022061        36.6     58
#> 4  2         2022043        34.3     21
#> 5  2         2022051        34.9     25
#> 6  2         2022052        35.3     25
```

Or in base R using `merge`:

```r
df2$year_month <- substr(df2$year_month_week, 1, 6)
merge(df2, df1, by = c('year_month', 'id'))[-1]
#>   id year_month_week temperature points
#> 1  2         2022043        34.3     21
#> 2  1         2022052        36.1     65
#> 3  1         2022053        36.3     65
#> 4  2         2022051        34.9     25
#> 5  2         2022052        35.3     25
#> 6  1         2022061        36.6     58
```